# git merge repeating conflicts

Tags: git, merge

I have a branch `master` and a branch `feature` which was checked out from `master`.

`master` gets commits pushed into it from other developers and I regularly merge `master` back into `feature`, so that it keeps up with new developments from other branches.

However, I keep getting the same conflicts in the same files every time I do a `git merge master`, although I resolved the conflict before and committed the changes.

Any ideas on what could be the cause for this and how to prevent it?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't sound right. Are you sure that these files are not changing?

Comment: All developers push on the same branch ?! I think you should make a dedicated branch for each developer. By the way, you mean, conflicts appear again ?! Source files are changed again ?! Your commits have gone ?! Do you mean this ? Or conflicts appear in new files pushed.

Comment: @kan: the files are changing but not in the lines that cause the conflict. In one case, after going through all the conflicting lines in the file and `git add`ing it again, git even removed it from the index because it was exactly the same as the one already present.

Comment: @KamranAmini: Each developer uses different branches for different features but they obviously end up pushing them into `master`. Sorry, I probably wasn't clear enough about that the first time.
The commits are not gone and some of the source files in `master` are changed again after the previous merge. Which leads me to think that this might be the cause for the problem... I would expect git to be smart enough to see that the conflicting part of the file has not been changed and thus it wouldn't mark it as a conflict, though...

Comment: I don't understand anyway, if you merged once, it doesn't merge the same again. Conflicts could happen only with new changes made after the merge. Or do you do rebase or stash?

Comment: No rebase or stashing. But apparently it's not that uncommon. So much that git has a tool to deal with this. See the link in ouah's answer below.

Comment: @borfast Maybe I am wrong, but the rerere is not very common actually, it is handy only if you merge different but similar branches differently or doing rebases a lot. The normal branch-merge workflow doesn't need it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First consider not merging integration branches into feature branches.

Second have a look to [git rerere](http://gitster.livejournal.com/41795.html) command and use it:

```
$ git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

> NAME
>
> ```
>   git-rerere - Reuse recorded resolution of conflicted merges
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>   In a workflow employing relatively long lived topic branches,
>   the developer sometimes needs to resolve the same conflicts
>   over and over again until the topic branches are done (either
>   merged to the "release" branch, or sent out and accepted upstream)
> ```

Comment: That looks very useful. I'll give that a try next time I try this particular branch merge. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, you suggested not merging integration branches into feature branches. In principle it sounds good (I didn't use to do it until recently) but how do you deal with long term branches? Do you merge them only at the very end, when you're done with them? That sometimes means _a lot_ of changes, which is dangerous and is exactly what we're trying to avoid by regularly merging `master` into `feature`.

Comment: You maybe want rebase feature onto a newer master instead, if your intent is that feature's changes are a few additions to master.